# How to test null value on nullable enum

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have documents with property _report_type, it supposed to contain a string "FTE", or "CAB".
In legacy document, it can be null or not exist at all (undefined), they are supposed to be "ContractorWorkReport".

My mapping:

```
    public class Order : Document, IBaseEntity<string>
    {
        [JsonProperty(Order = 70, PropertyName = "orderData")]
        public OrderData Data { get; set; }      
    }

    public class OrderData
    {   

        [JsonProperty(Order = 60, PropertyName = "_order_type")]
        public OrderType? OrderType { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum OrderType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "TFE")]
        ContractorWorkReport,
        [EnumMember(Value = "CAB")]
        BudgetElectricMeter
    }
```

My query based on that :

```
var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>($"/dbs/{_databaseId}/colls/{CollectionId}");

    if (filter.OrderType.Value == OrderType.ContractorWorkReport)
        query = query.Where(o =>  o.Data.OrderType == null || !o.Data.OrderType.HasValue || o.Data.OrderType == filter.OrderType);
    else
        query = query.Where(o => o.Data.OrderType == filter.OrderType);
```

This query crashes because of the o.Data.OrderType == null, error message is :
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Sql.SqlNullLiteral' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Sql.SqlNumberLiteral'.'

How can fix this? Right now, i do this, but it's dirty...

```
if (filter.OrderType.Value == OrderType.ContractorWorkReport) 
            query = query.Where(o =>  o.Data.OrderType != OrderType.BudgetElectricMeter);
        else
            query = query.Where(o => o.Data.OrderType == filter.OrderType);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you use this for the first parameter in CreateDocumentQuery : `UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId)`

To answer your question, you are comparing an int to a null. `o.Data.OrderType`, being an enum, resolves to an int. You may want to compare that to the default enum value `0` or query over documents where `o.Data.OrderType` is not a key at all

Comment: Thank you for answer : UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId) is way better indeed. For the default enum value, the enum here is nullable, so i would expect it understand what null is. I can test but pretty sure it won't work as it can be null or undefined.  for the "or query over documents where o.Data.OrderType is not a key at all", not sure what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom The enum is not nullable as far as cosmosDB is concerned. Just read that exception. You are trying to convert `null` into an int. Clearly, cosmosDB (or its client) is interpreting your enum as an int. Which is NOT nullable. 
I would recommend casting your enum to a string if you want to use null

Comment: thanks but how would you cast your enum in a string? I tried .ToString() and other methods, but never understood by the provider to "query" it corretly